Accessing Context API From Client Side to Server Side Component In NextJS CREATES MULTI FETCH
I've tried to make a SSR component which fetches GET with token in headers. As I don't have the access of ContextAPI/Web Storage APIs, I was trying to get that from a client component as a prop.
Here is my code:
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
"use client";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/lib/contexts/auth.context.provider";
import GetOrdersTable from "./_utils/get-orders-table";

const Page = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuthContext();

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
      <GetOrdersTable token={auth?.refreshToken || "dummyToken"} />
    </Suspense>
  )
};
export default Page;

But the problem is it is fetching the same endpoints until it's getting final response for first request or any arbitrary request.
Also printing the error: Warning: A component was suspended by an uncached promise. Creating promises inside a Client Component or hook is not yet supported, except via a Suspense-compatible library or framework.

Hence, I don't want to mess with client-server render, rather just want to get the token from local Storage wile fetching using server Action.
That is what I want. Thank you!

In this case, we should know that we can't have Context API in SSR. But we need to store some data to access it both in SSR and CSR. In this case we can use cookies API of nextjs and js cookie functions . Rest of the values in Context API will be used as usual.
